# How do I express this query in SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to query a table in an existing sqlite database. The data must first be subsetted as such, from a user input:

```
query(Data.num == input)
```

Then I want to find the max and min of **another field: date** in this subset.

I have tried using func.min/max, as well as union, but received an error saying the columns do not match. One of the issues here is that func.min/max need to be used as query arguments, not filter.

```
ids = session.query(Data).filter(Data.num == input)
q = session.query(func.max(Data.date),
        func.min(Data.date))
ids.union(q).all()

ArgumentError: All selectables passed to CompoundSelect must have identical numbers of columns; select #1 has 12 columns, select #2 has 2
```

Similarly, if I use func.max and min separately, the error says #2 has 1 column.

I think seeing this query in SQL might help as well.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of saying "I have tried using… but received an error", show us the code, and the exception.

Comment: @abarnert this was my attempt at a union, above. Although I'm not sure if a union is the correct approach. I want to subset by one variable, then take a min and max across another variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution works. You first need to set up the query, then filter the data down afterwards.

```
        query = session.query(Data.num, func.min(Data.date),
            func.max(Data.date), Data.date)
        query = query.filter(Data.num == input)
        query = query.all()
```